# Sustaining linear warfare in futuristic combat

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, far-future, tactics

In my sci-fi setting, I’m looking for a way to have linear infantry formations, or something similar, in a world where airplanes and machine-guns also exist. It is made possible by the existence of heavy plated armor of an unobtainium material that weighs roughly half of steel, but can stop rifle-caliber bullets at medium range consistently. I can settle for loose order formations as well. This armor is very effective, and therefore is countered by either massive volumes of fire, very precise, high-caliber rife fire, or CQB. It is in a setting where the majority of these wars take place at the bottom of a dried-up ocean, so most armies are armed with bolt-action rifles, as more complicated machinery tends to break down from the dust & dirt in this desert. Aircraft and tanks are extremely vulnerable due to the presence of effective, reusable, man-portable guides missile launchers. Can you think of a way that linear warfare could exist in this setting, or ways of modifying the tactics or technology to accommodate for something similar? I am open to change.

Comment: Dust and dirt prevent anything but bolt-action rifles... and also man-portable, reusable, guided missile launchers?  That would seem to pretty much negate your fancy armour as well.

Comment: The vast bulk of infantry casualties are artillery related. Artillery shells do not care about any armour you could put on someone. Aircraft & tanks realistically can't be eliminated just by making them vulnerable, they provide capabilities beyond just survivability.

Comment: I don't get it. *Tanks* are extremely vulnerable, and yet at the same time you want to have 19th century style battles with infantry shooting bullets at infantry? If tanks cannot survive on the battlefield, infantry marching in formation is dead on arrival. (And I don't see in what way an AK-47 is so much more complicated than a bolt-action rifle that it cannot work because of dust while the rifle can.)

Comment: The AK-47 is actually infamous for its ability to keep working despite being used, abused, dirty, muddy and/or neglected. This is at the expense of accuracy compared to other rifles.

Answer (score 6):

So - there's lots in your description that's contradictory...

However, I think I can solve most of your problem:

**The Environment naturally inhibits wireless communication**

That is, no Radios, no remote communication - nothing but Line-of-sight and visual communication (which means your guided missiles are Laser guided)

This means that in order to keep battlefield cohesion, you can't have a large, widespread force. Squad based skirmishing tactics are also very risky because they can't easily co-ordinate with HQ, call for backup, report findings etc.

The result is that there is a move away from dynamic platoon level engagements, with officers on the ground making command decisions (e.g. we are on patrol as a platoon, we see something and go investigate as a result of that, we decide to alter the plan for *reasons*) and towards a more regimented and formal style of engagement. Lots of Signal flags and semaphore to direct the flow of Battle.

You could make an argument that WW1 still had (to a degree) linear combat of sorts due to Trenches. Whereas once Radios got small and cheap enough to no longer be a command-level asset, that's when we start to see more dispersed Warfare, more combined arms as now assets and units can communicate with each other.

Some other points - the traditional ranks/columns of Infantry were also a function of the relative inaccuracy of firearms, necessitating accuracy by Volume. You've mentioned you have precision guided weapons (Missiles) - however unguided projectiles (Bullets etc.) are affected by Atmospheric conditions and no way to correct it. If you were to have that the bottom of your dried up Ocean has very strong and unpredictable winds (insert reasons) that make accuracy beyond 100 meters for unguided projectiles difficult/dubious - that would be a factor too.

Comment: i mean WW2 happened while the vast bulk of soldiers didn't have radios at lower levels. Armoured forces had them, but outside of the US forces seeing them below battalion level outside of armoured forces was very rare. The commonwealth sometimes had them in company HQs but not always. While the platoon as the primary level of maneuver took hold during WW1 with their almost complete absence at low levels.

Answer (score 6):

**This is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609)**

> The reason for the large casualties in Civil War battles is that the weapons were ahead of the tactics.  The rifled musket had an effective range of a couple hundred yards.  Very effective range.  But when they got these new weapons they kept the old tactics, and the worst thing they believed was that to mass your fire against your opponent you had to mass your men.  So you advanced shoulder-to-shoulder across an open field against this deadly fire. (Civil War historian Shelby Foote)

*What you're asking for isn't just improbable, it's irrational*

The U.S. Civil War happened at about the same time as militaries across the globe were experiencing this very same problem. In the "good old days" rifles threw slugs that kinda went all over the place. Consequently, in order to bring plenty of predictable firepower to bear, you had to bunch your soldiers together.

What inventions like the Minié ball and rifled barrels did was bring to pass the golden age of the [sharpshooter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpshooter), which hasn't really ended. Today we call them *snipers,* and if memory serves, most sniper rifles are bolt action. Could be wrong about that, but that's what I'm remembering.

**Unobtainium**

I get the idea that you're creating armor that is impervious to at least small weapons fire. Heck, let's make it impervious to all forms of kinetic firepower. Heck-heck, let's make it impervious to all forms of firepower, even the heat of a nuclear blast.

Problem #1 is that you can't perfectly cover your soldiers. There are weaknesses at joints, etc. There's always somewhere a sniper can sneak a bullet through.

But another problem (and the bigger one) is that bullet holes aren't the only way to kill soldiers. They can also be killed or, worse, disabled<sup>1</sup> via *concussion.* Armor can stop bullets, but they can only do so much to stop the kinetic force of the bullet. Modern flak jackets try to spread out the kinetic energy so that it will, at most, cause bruises. But hit that armor with a big enough shell and your soldier is just as dead.

**Well-armored soldiers standing in a line have a name: canon fodder**

My point is this: so long as you allow machine guns, air planes, tanks, and (I assume) artillery, the idea of soldiers conveniently lining up to get shot isn't just irrational. I'm sorry to say, *it's ridiculous.*

I can only agree with @AlexP, you're trying to use 18th and 19th century infantry tactics with 20th and 21st century weaponry. What I suspect will happen is this:

- At the first engagement where tanks meet infantry armed with anti-tank weapons, the infantry will conveniently line up because that's what you want them to do.
- The tanks, not suffering the same lack of judgement as the infantry, roll to a stop behind some equally convenient hills and send forward observers to the tops of the hills to stealthily sight where the conveniently lined up infantry is.
- Using whatever communications is appropriate (in deference to @TheDemonLord's answer, we'll have them use binoculars and some creative modification to [naval flag signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_flag_signalling) to indicate where the slow-moving conveniently-lined-up infantry is.
- Shells fly, soldiers die, the infantry scatters...
- And never makes that mistake again.

*I'm willing to delete this frame challenge — if you can reasonably explain why you want the infantry to do something that's been considered a bad idea for 200+ years. If airplanes and tanks are on the field, so are rocket-propelled artillery. The biggest reason we don't line up soldiers today is that regardless what armaments they can carry, it's always possible to toss firepower at them from a long, long, long way away.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Whether or not disabling soldiers has an effect depends on the culture of the soldiers, both before they became soldiers and within the military itself. A Scandinavian soldier once commented to me that one tactic was to wound, rather than kill, infantry. Compassion and honor causes their comrades to try to save their lives. Thus, wounding one soldier can have the effect of temporarily removing two or three soldiers from the field, causing an advantage. No, it's not a universally predictable tactic,  but I bring up the point because with artillery you'd have a lot of unobtanium-covered soldiers laying on the field dazed, confused, and potentially dying, calling "medic!"*</sub>

Comment: Can you think of a way to modify the formations to be slightly more survivable, as I asked in the post? Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: AI controlled defenses have rendered all forms of range attack completely ineffective.**

I think this works and is not even that far off from the reality of the modern battlefield. A missile is fired at a bunch of ground troops. Their main weapon is a Predator style shoulder mount which they can control, but can also be taken over by the AI to eliminate incoming threats. The AI selects relevant troopers and has their shoulder guns shoot down the incoming missile.

It also has a high powered laser for shooting down smaller projectiles. It's possible to overwhelm this defense but, as you wanted, it makes sense that this requires overwhelming firepower. These shoulder mounts are quite good, tap into enormous amounts of power, never overheat, etc, so the limits on how much firepower they can stop is up to your imagination while staying within the realm of plausible sci-fi. Imagine a trooper walking across a battlefield, 10 snipers trying to get him, but his shoulder cannon (and that of any of his nearby buddies) are simply vaporizing the bullets in mid-air. They never get hit.

But troopers also have armor that's pretty capable, so even if you get right up on someone and point blank shoot them in the face, anything less than a tank round will hardly phase them. You'd really have to drill their armor repeatedly in the same spot.

What DOES work on them are unobtanium vibroblades. Or, erm, beam sabers. Or what is basically hand-held mining equipment. Or whatever your preferred melee solution is. The AI defenses are entirely effective on incoming rounds but can only do so much to deter a 50 pound vibrosledge being driven in by a Mk34 Tactical Armor Suit.

*Note: I'm assuming melee is the answer, but "lining up and focusing fire at distances in the 10 - 100 meter range" could work here too. Kinda like playing a game of old Red Alert, it's best to focus targets down one at a time, as this overwhelms the AI defenses, provided you do it from short enough range that it just doesn't have time to stop everything.*

**Option 2: Technology has broken down.**

I'm feeling something like Warhammer 40k vibes here, but taken slightly more extreme, where projectile technology has simply been lost over time, and no one really thinks about it, because they are too busy trying to smash each other with hammers. Maybe there was a reason for this, once. Temporary supply shortages. Or the only people left on the world are basically mass produced infantry grunts who are taught nothing but war and the planet actually has no one left who is not a soldier coming out of the soldier mills (perhaps run by AIs, set in motion a thousand years ago). The logistics and technology for maintaining any form of ranged combat has long since been lost, right down to the factory level, but melee weapons are easy to maintain.

**Option 3: Honor and Culture**

They absolutely can blast each other from range but the tactics you desired became the style demanded by honor and tradition. Lining up, Napoleon era style, and exchanging manly rifle fire, is simply how it's done. Firing from cover? Trenches? No one would dare shame themselves and their families with such ideas! Perhaps most of the modern weapons are now banned, and it's a war crime to use them. (We already ban some other perfectly effective war tools as being too cruel or unpredictable, even for war, so it's not a huge exaggeration to think that some future society could actually ban a great many things. "Anyone who believes so greatly in their cause as to murder others over it, must also believe greatly enough to stand in an open field and do it via honorable exchanges of unrifled gunfire." The old men who came up with this idea thought it would end wars forever. It didn't. Turns out we're happy to stand in dusty, dead ocean beds and shoot at each other with inaccurate short range guns if that's all we're given.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons rigid line formations were used is low accuracy of weapons, but mainly meele combat that would occure once the two formations meet and cavalry. Loose formations will have advantage in ranged combat most of the time, but if it's expected that the range can eventually become much closer (assuming the unit survives the process of of getting there in good enough shape) a rigid formation can pay off even when beying less efficient at a distance. 
 
Off course marching towards the enemy with bayonets ready while plowing through aerial bombardment, artillery and machine gun fire deffinitely requires some very good measures against all that, as well as this "Drive me closer, I want to hit them with my sword!" tactic having to be worth it. It's much easier to break enemy's morale at close range, but for that to happen your troops must be alive and capable of hurting them. 
So I'm not going to go into detail about some specific ways to make it survivable, since others have already offered some pretty good solutions, but I recomend checking out what people said elsewhere about modern/sci-fi meele combat as well, since it was a major part of warfare from 30 years war all the way to America's civil war and had a major influence on how infantry fought at the time. 

Also, depending on how much Napoleonic-like you want it to be, I recomend taking a look at these two videos, they summarise very well how and why they used lines as well as a wide range of other tactics.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uw3wlU3eYsc *Napoleonic Infantry Tactics* 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-GybrfE42U *Why did soldiers fight in lines?*

Answer (score 0):

The unobtainium armor could be powered by a reactor which has an accumulative resonating effect in the vicinity of other reactors of the same type. A single suit of armor on its own would barely be able to move but add another suit next to it and the reactor produces more power. Kind of like an efficiency bonus. A group of armored suits would allow for rapid speed and maneuverability. This effect could have a time delay, taking time to work at full efficiency and taking time to lose that efficiency. Like taking your foot off the gas at high speed. Your vehicle still retains a higher speed for a while.

If the effects were drastic enough, it would necessitate the return to tight infantry formations. If a group of armored soldiers becomes super soldiers, then there would be an incentive to utilize the older formations. Perhaps the armor becomes effective enough for the soldiers to avoid incoming artillery. They might scatter quickly and then regroup before their suit power generation drops too much. If they are fast enough, they could potentially overtake tanks and other such vehicles, ripping them apart with brute strength. Hulk smash! No need for the missile launchers.

Such an armor would potentially allow the soldiers to carry and employ much higher caliber weapons. Perhaps an AI aided anti-aircraft round? Maybe a railgun of some type? Railguns need a lot of energy, so the armor would need enough nearby reactors to make it viable. They also do not have much in the way of moving parts, which works well in your world setting.

Excess energy could also allow for the generation of a static field which protects the armor from dust and dirt. Maybe it is even powerful enough to partially deflect bullets and other such incoming hazards, but only if there are enough suits nearby.